# Does Amazon beanstalk automatically prevent DDoS

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ddos

Does Amazon Beanstalk automatically prevent (distributed) denial of service attack? If not, whats the most convenient way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't prevent DoS attacks, you'll have to detect and prevent such attacks by yourself. There are differnt ways to protect your application against DoS attacks, you can google for it. Here are a few links which may help you:

- [aiCache DoS attack identification and mitigation](http://aws.amazon.com/customerapps/3351?_encoding=UTF8&queryArg=searchQuery&x=0&fromSearch=1&y=0&searchPath=all&searchQuery=aicache)
- [Amazon Web Services: Overview of Security Processes](http://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/overview-of-security-processes/)
- [Wikipedia: SYN cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syn_cookies)
- [Amazon Forum: DoS attack](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=289622)

Answer (score 9):

I believe it does

> New – AWS Shield AWS Shield is a new managed service that protects
>   your web applications against DDoS (Distributed Denial of Service)
>   attacks. It works in conjunction with Elastic Load Balancing, Amazon
>   CloudFront, and Amazon Route 53 and protects you from DDoS attacks of
>   many types, shapes, and sizes. There are two tiers of service:
>
> AWS Shield Standard is available to all AWS customers at no extra
>   cost. It protects you from 96% of the most common attacks today,
>   including SYN/ACK floods, Reflection attacks, and HTTP slow reads.
>   This protection is applied automatically and transparently to your
>   Elastic Load Balancers, CloudFront distributions, and Route 53
>   resources.
>
> AWS Shield Advanced provides additional DDoS mitigation capability for
>   volumetric attacks, intelligent attack detection, and mitigation for
>   attacks at the application & network layers. You get 24×7 access to
>   our DDoS Response Team (DRT) for custom mitigation during attacks,
>   advanced real time metrics and reports, and DDoS cost protection to
>   guard against bill spikes in the aftermath of a DDoS attack.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-shield-protect-your-applications-from-ddos-attacks/

Answer (score 0):

There are several kinds of doss. Since your ec2 public IP address is behind aws eb, I think your ec2 instance is at least safe from layer3/4 ddos.